# Chrome puppeteer headless false in aws server Error: Failed to launch chrome

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, google-chrome, puppeteer

Puppeteer actually working fine in AWS linux server when running in headless:true mode, but when i set it to headless:false the error says "Error: Failed to launch chrome!".

I tried using xvfb but the output quality got lessen.

Is it possible or are there any alternative option aside to **use xvfb** to run headless:false in aws server as i need the GUI for my added extensions to run.

```
const pathToExtension = __dirname;
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
        `--enable-usermedia-screen-capturing`,
        `--allow-http-screen-capture`,
        `--no-sandbox`,
        `--auto-select-desktop-capture-source=${source_tab}`,
        `--disable-setuid-sandbox`,
        `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`,
        `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
        `--disable-web-security`,
        `--use-gl=egl`,
    ],
    executablePath: 'google-chrome'
});
```

**ERROR:**

```
(node:980) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
    at onClose (/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Launcher.js:349:14)
    at ChildProcess.helper.addEventListener (/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Launcher.js:339:60)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
(node:980) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:980) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```